# Embedded image shrinking in email clients like Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, email-client

I'm trying to embed an image in an email compatible HTML file.

Instead of adding the image URL, which can pose a security threat, I'm embedding the image in the  tag used in the HTML file.

```
<img alt="" border="0" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA............">
```

The image which I embed seems to reduce to 80% of it's original size in the email client. Following is a screenshot of the how the file looks in a browser :

HTML file when viewed in a browser
[image: HTML file when viewed in a browser]

Following is a screenshot of the how the file looks in an email client (Outlook for Office 365) :

HTML file when viewed in an email client
[image: HTML file when viewed in an email client]

As you can see the image seems to shrink in the email client. The dimension are given below:

```
Original     : 800px X 600px
Email client : 640px X 480px

Width  = 800 x 0.8 = 640px
Height = 600 x 0.8 = 480px
```

Can someone please suggest how to fit the image in a container? And why the image is shrinking in Outlook?

You can refer this HTML file :

Google Drive : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Me70-HIkLAB__BY_skOhyBXKDZj3lKVc

JSFiddle     : http://jsfiddle.net/jv16m794

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you supply the actual HTML you're using to display this image? We need to see the width properties you're setting which could be amended to stop this. But this is a potential fix. We can't promise anything without seeing any code.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify... Can you provide your HTML in a code editor like Codepen or JSFiddle? Google domains are blocked by many corporate firewalls, mine included.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein  I've added the HTML code in the below Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jv16m794/

Comment: Hi Aman, has the fix I provided below helped at all? Keen to find out if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Hi @Digital_Frankenstein . The solution provided by you worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this in Litmus and I'm only seeing this issue in 120dpi screen zoom versions of Outlook.
Here is an article going through the 120dpi screen settings and how it affects email - https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/dpi_scaling_in_outlook_2007-2013/

I've tested a couple of things and found the fix.
Amend the head of your email with this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->
   </head>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Digital_Frankenstein
It worked perfectly for the sample which I had provided. 
However, there were minor issues with some of the scenarios so I went on with content ID (cid) for images in the email HTMLs.

Comment: Thank you! This is top answer! It's works!